# ASP.NET MVC PostAuthorizeRequest (and other events) not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, global-asax

I'm working on the mvcForum project (on codeplex) and want to remove as much code as possible from the global.asax file - mostly to make it easier to integrate mvcForum into existing ASP.NET MVC application without changing too much code.

I need to hook into the application events to be able to set the correct CultureInfo (depending on the users' choice etc) and other things.

This isn't a problem with this in the global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() {
       // Some code here!
}
```

But when I try moving the code somewhere else, the event never happens.
What I'm doing is this:

```
public MVCForumBootstrapper(HttpApplication app) {
    app.PostAuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(app_PostAuthorizeRequest);
}
```

And this in the global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start() {
      var strapper = new MVCForumBootstrapper(this);
    }
```

I was kind of expecting this to work in exactly the same way?

What am I doing wrong/have I missed?

Thanks, Steen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this in the `Init` method of Global.asax. In `Application_Start` it's too late too hook events:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    var strapper = new MVCForumBootstrapper(this);
}
```