# MVC Application_PostAuthorizeRequest event not firing when using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have an ASP.NET Web API project and I need to access session `HttpContext.Current.Session` but it's always null in web api

accoriding to [Accessing Session Using ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api) question I need Application_PostAuthorizeRequest event.

### Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        ...

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            if (IsWebApiRequest())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
            }
        }

        private bool IsWebApiRequest()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative);
        }

}
```

but the problem is ***Application_PostAuthorizeRequest*** event never fires.
I recently upgraded my project from MVC4 to MVC5.

I can only catch **Application_AuthenticateRequest** but when I copy the same code in this event it doesn't help and session is still null

**Update:**

I'm using SignalR to send instant notifications.
I found out when I comment this line `app.MapSignalR()` eveything works as I expected and I can catch the event.

**Startup.cs**:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
            //app.MapSignalR(); when i comment this line I can catch the event
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                // TODO expired time hardcoded
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
    }
}
```

can somebody explain what's wrong? why when I comment `app.MapSignalR()` everything works fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PostAuthenticateRequest or PostAuthorizeRequest?

Comment: sorry I was confused with event names, `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` I should edit my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC PostAuthorizeRequest (and other events) not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974673/asp-net-mvc-postauthorizerequest-and-other-events-not-firing)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, I tried the solution but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Finally I found the solution for my own question. I have no idea exactly what's going on but when I register SignalR before Owin and WebApi it works fine, so I moved `app.MapSignalR();` to the top.

here is the final Code of `Configuration` method of  `Startup.cs` :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var currentCultureName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
    app.MapSignalR();
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCultureName);

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```